Что делать если интернет не работает на конкретном устройстве с конкретной сим карте?
В один день на телефоне перестал работать интернет, но только на определённой сим карте, но звонки и смс работают. На других устройствах эта сим карта работает в полной мере, также другие сим карты хорошо работают на этом телефоне, но стоит их соеденить и интернета нет. Передача данных точно включена, но иконка сверху выглядит так будто бы и нет. Пробовали заменить сим карту в салоне связи, но с сохранением номера телефона (думали дело в контактах), пробовали перезагружать устройство, пробовали смотреть в настройках долго и тщательно,также на этом устройстве есть два слота для сим карт, поэтому не побрезговали погонять туда сюда карту,  ждали даже новый платёжный месяц, но все варианты провал. Единственное, что ещё думаем сделать это сбросить устройство до заводских настроек, но очень хотелось бы этого избежать (много мороки с переносом данных). Может кто встречал подобное и знает что делать?

вам бы обратиться в профильную ветку своего телефона на 4pda, там вам быстрее помогут

Это проблема на стороне провайдера. Где-то у него пара IMEI:phone-number  режется на роутинг в интернет (из-за чего это могло произойти -- не знаю)

phone-number, а не ICCID -- поскольку вы пишете, что меняли симку, но номер оставили прежним
